# Load multiple methods from dll at runtime C#

Tags: c#, dll, runtime, .net-assembly

I am working on "plugin" system to my program. I want to redistribute multiple dll's for example: "myAwesomePlugin1.dll", "myAwesomePlugin2.dll". Each of these files have method called for example: "doSmthAwesome(string msg)".

Now, when I have all prepared I want to load these two methods and run them: 
1st doSmthAwesome from Plugin1 
2nd doSmthAwesome from Plugin2

Unfortunatelly, I don't know why, but when I load these dll's, second one copies method from first dll. How I can do it in proper way, to have both these methods?

Heres my code:

```
string doSmthAwesomeFrom1(string msg)
{
     string value = "";
     try
     {
          Assembly a = null;
          a = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginDirectory + "/" + IkarosConfiguration.getValueFromKey("FIRST_PLUGIN"));
          Type classType = a.GetType("awesomePlugin.awesomePlugin");
          MethodInfo mi = classType.GetMethod("doSmthAwesome");
          object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
          value = mi.Invoke(obj, new object[] { msg});
     }
     catch
     {
     }

     return value;
}


string doSmthAwesomeFrom2(string msg)
{
     string value = "";
     try
     {
          Assembly a = null;
          a = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginDirectory + "/" + IkarosConfiguration.getValueFromKey("SECOND_PLUGIN"));
          Type classType = a.GetType("awesomePlugin.awesomePlugin");
          MethodInfo mi = classType.GetMethod("doSmthAwesome");
          object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
          value = mi.Invoke(obj, new object[] { msg});
     }
     catch
     {
     }

     return value;
}
```